# Why am I being prompted for my password for updates in the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, password

Recently the iOS App Store has started to prompt me for my password for updating apps in the App Store. Is there something I can do to change this back to the way it was?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the restriction settings may be the cause. Even though I have a PIN on the home screen, it prompts me for a password when I update.

I went to Settings > General > Restrictions > Require Passwords and set it to 15 minutes. I'm not sure how it got changed to this, possibly an update?

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. What you describe is a bug. If you try to update from a page within the store, it will prompt you for your pass. If you update from the actual Updates tab, it won't.

Comment: Hitting update all triggers the prompt as well.